# Any help with proving this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Consider a nice enough function $$\begin{align*}
u: & \mathbb{R}^{3}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}
\\ & (x, t) \to u(x,t)
\end{align*}$$Then, we use $\alpha=(\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\alpha_{3})$ as tuple. We have the following operators and notations $$\begin{align*}
J &=  x + 2it \nabla && x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}
\\ &= (x_{1}+ 2it \partial x_{1},x_{2}+2it\partial x_{2}, x_{3}+2it\partial x_{3})
\\ &= (J_{1},J_{2},J_{3}) 
\\ 
\\ \nabla^{\alpha} &= \partial x_{1}^{\alpha_{1}} \partial x_{2}^{\alpha_{2}} \partial x_{3}^{\alpha_{3}} && \alpha_{1}+ \alpha_{2}+ \alpha_{3}=|\alpha|
\\ 
\\ J^{\alpha} &= J_{1}^{\alpha_{1}} J_{2}^{\alpha_{2}} J_{3}^{\alpha_{3}} 
\end{align*}$$
Also, $\|\cdot\|_{2}$ is the $L^{2}$ norm with respect to space variable $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ , and $\nabla$ is also always with respect to space variables $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$

With these settings, I'm wondering how to prove the inequality $$\begin{align*}
\sup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}} |u| \leq \frac{C}{|t|^{3/2}} \sum\limits_{|\alpha|\leq 2} \|J^{\alpha} u\|_{2}
\end{align*}$$
I indeed already obtained 2 hints:

1 )
Use the identity: $$\begin{align*}
Ju= 2it \overline{M} \nabla (Mu) && \text{ where } M(x,t) = \exp\left( -i \frac{|x|^{2}}{4t} \right)
\end{align*}$$
2 )
For function $f(x,t)$, apply the inequality $$\begin{align*}
\sup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}} |f|^{2} \leq C_{0} \|\nabla f\|_{2} \cdot \sum\limits_{|\alpha|=2} \|\nabla^{\alpha} f\|_{2}
\end{align*}$$ I can prove the 1 ) identity. However, I really got stuck at using the given inequality to prove the inequality. Any help on this? Thanks!